# Group notification, example in string

Tags: php, notifications

I have string with notification, I use explode by new line ("\n") and variables by | tag for show notification, I need group notification but I do not have idea how, please check exaxmple:

```
$string = '
|User Mike upload new picture test11.jpg|15.04.2014. 10:13 am|
|User Mike upload new picture test33.jpg|15.04.2014. 10:13 am|
|User Mike upload new picture test33.jpg|15.04.2014. 10:11 am|
|User Mike upload new picture test44.jpg|15.04.2014. 10:11 am|
|User Mike upload new picture test11.jpg|10.04.2014. 10:10 am|
|User Mike upload new picture test88.jpg|8.04.2014. 12:01 am|
|User Mike upload new picture test23.jpg|8.04.2014. 01:20 am|
|User Mike upload new picture test4.jpg|7.04.2014. 02:02 am|
|User Lorena add new project 12|6.04.2014. 10:11 am|
|User Lorena add new project 32|6.04.2014. 9:11 am|
';
```

I need convert this to string:

```
$string = '
|User Mike upload 4 new pictures (pictures list)|15.04.2014.|
|User Mike upload new picture test.jpg|10.04.2014.|
|User Mike upload 2 new pictures (pictures list)|8.04.2014.|
|User Mike upload new picture test.jpg|7.04.2014.|
|User Lorena add 2 new project|6.04.2014.|
';
```

Rules: * When is few same notification added in one day code must join in one notification, does anybody have idea how do this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have all the data in the $string, you can split each line by the whitespace to get the user which will be found at [1] ([0] would be the "|User") and the date which will be found at [5].

You then would need to split the [5] by the "|" to get only the date which will be found at [5][1].

once you got the [1] & [5][1], lets say you have an additional object/array outside the loop,
so that on each line;

It would loop into this additional object/array and if it is found using the [1] (which is the user) then it would check the [5][1] (which is the date) and if it is found, then it increment the int stored inside. 
However if it is not found than it would add it to the existing array/object

This would be my way of fixing this problem which will give you something like this;

```
$array[1][0] = user
$array[1][1] = date
$array[1][2] = amount
$array[2][0] = user
etc...
```

you can then use this to provide the expected output..